# image saved from camera activity (my own) turns up corrupted (size 0)

Tags: android

I'm taking a picture using my own camera and trying to save the result to the file system (/data/data/package.name/file/captured_photo1.jpeg).
When i try it on the emulator it seems to work - creates a file size 18474 bytes and displays it (i guess this is the emulator's default photo) .
The problem is that when i try it on my GalaxyS the image on the file system is 0 bytes

the code:

```
outStream = getApplicationContext().openFileOutput(SolveCaptureActivity.FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);      
outStream.write(data); //data is of type Byte[]
outStream.flush();
outStream.close();
```

does anyone have any idea what could it be?

**UPDATED:**
i found out (from the log) that one of the callbacks i pass to my takePicture method isn't called. and it's the one that actually saves it.

the data[] that i get in the rawCallback is null both on the phone and the emulator, but on the emulator the callback is called and it works

this is the whole Activity code:

```
public class SolveCaptureActivity extends Activity {
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.solve_capture);

        preview = new Preview(this);
        ((FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.preview)).addView(preview);

        buttonClick = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonCapture);
        buttonClick.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(View v) { 
            preview.camera.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawCallback, jpegCallback);
            Intent gotoImagePreview = new Intent(v.getContext(), CapturedImagePreview.class);
            startActivityForResult(gotoImagePreview, 0);
          }
        });

        buttonFocus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonFocus);
        buttonFocus.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
              preview.camera.autoFocus(new AutoFocusCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onAutoFocus(boolean success, Camera camera) {
                    Camera.Parameters camParam = camera.getParameters();
                    camParam.setFocusMode(Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO);
                    camera.setParameters(camParam);
                }
              });
            }
        });

        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate'd");
      }

      // Called when shutter is opened
      ShutterCallback shutterCallback = new ShutterCallback() {
        public void onShutter() {
          Log.d(TAG, "onShutter'd");
        }
      };

      PictureCallback rawCallback = new PictureCallback() {
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
          Log.d(TAG, "onPictureTaken - raw");
        }
      };

      PictureCallback jpegCallback = new PictureCallback() { // <8>
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
          FileOutputStream outStream = null;
          if (data == null){
              Log.d("@@--DATA--@@, msg","=NULL");
          }
          try {         
            Log.d("@@--DIR--@@", Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath());
            Log.d("@@--Size--@@", Integer.toString(data.length));
            outStream = getApplicationContext().openFileOutput(SolveCaptureActivity.FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);

            outStream.write(data);
            outStream.flush();
            outStream.close();
            Log.d(TAG, "onPictureTaken - wrote bytes: " + data.length);
          } catch (FileNotFoundException e) { // <10>
            e.printStackTrace();
          } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          } finally {
          }
          Log.d(TAG, "onPictureTaken - jpeg");
        }
      };

    }
```

this is the log:

```
09-01 18:44:38.403: WARN/CameraService(6488): takePicture (pid 6585)
09-01 18:44:38.403: INFO/ShotSingle(6488): ShotSingle::takePicture start
09-01 18:44:38.403: ERROR/CameraHardwareSec(6488): stopPreview()
09-01 18:44:38.403: ERROR/SecCamera(6488): cancelAutofocus()
09-01 18:44:38.403: ERROR/SecCamera(6488): cancelAutofocus() end, 0, 4
09-01 18:44:38.409: ERROR/SecCamera(6488): stopPreview()
09-01 18:44:38.409: ERROR/SecCamera(6488): fimc_v4l2_streamoff()
09-01 18:44:38.433: ERROR/CameraHardwareSec(6488): stopPreview() end
09-01 18:44:38.433: INFO/ShotSingle(6488): ShotSingle::takePicture end
09-01 18:44:38.433: INFO/ActivityManager(3135): Starting activity: Intent { cmp=cs.workshop.solvedroid/.CapturedImagePreview }
09-01 18:44:38.437: WARN/CameraService(6488): setPreviewCallbackFlag (pid 6585)
09-01 18:44:38.437: DEBUG/Preview(6585): onPreviewFrame called at: 1314891878438
09-01 18:44:38.457: DEBUG/SecCamera(6488): passed fmt = 1498831189 found pixel format[3]: YUV 4:2:2 packed, CbYCrY
09-01 18:44:38.467: WARN/CameraService(6488): width(640), height(480), format:jpeg
09-01 18:44:38.523: WARN/System.err(6585): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/cs.workshop.solvedroid/files/captured_photo2.jpeg (No such file or directory)
09-01 18:44:38.542: WARN/System.err(6585):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSFileSystem.openImpl(Native Method)
09-01 18:44:38.542: WARN/System.err(6585):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSFileSystem.open(OSFileSystem.java:152)
09-01 18:44:38.542: WARN/System.err(6585):     at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:82)
09-01 18:44:38.542: WARN/System.err(6585):     at android.app.ContextImpl.openFileInput(ContextImpl.java:448)
09-01 18:44:38.542: WARN/System.err(6585):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.openFileInput(ContextWrapper.java:152)
09-01 18:44:38.542: WARN/System.err(6585):     at cs.workshop.solvedroid.CapturedImagePreview.onCreate(CapturedImagePreview.java:29)
09-01 18:44:38.542: WARN/System.err(6585):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
09-01 18:44:38.543: WARN/System.err(6585):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
09-01 18:44:38.543: WARN/System.err(6585):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
09-01 18:44:38.545: WARN/System.err(6585):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
09-01 18:44:38.545: WARN/System.err(6585):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
09-01 18:44:38.547: WARN/System.err(6585):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-01 18:44:38.547: WARN/System.err(6585):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-01 18:44:38.549: WARN/System.err(6585):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
09-01 18:44:38.549: WARN/System.err(6585):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-01 18:44:38.551: WARN/System.err(6585):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
09-01 18:44:38.553: WARN/System.err(6585):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
09-01 18:44:38.553: WARN/System.err(6585):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
09-01 18:44:38.555: WARN/System.err(6585):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-01 18:44:38.643: WARN/CameraService(6488): stopPreview (pid 6585)
09-01 18:44:38.643: ERROR/CameraHardwareSec(6488): stopPreview()
09-01 18:44:38.643: ERROR/SecCamera(6488): cancelAutofocus()
09-01 18:44:38.643: ERROR/SecCamera(6488): cancelAutofocus() end, 0, 4
09-01 18:44:38.643: ERROR/SecCamera(6488): stopPreview()
09-01 18:44:38.645: ERROR/SecCamera(6488): stopPreview: m_flag_camera_start is zero
09-01 18:44:38.645: ERROR/CameraHardwareSec(6488): stopPreview() end
09-01 18:44:38.645: WARN/CameraService(6488): stopPreview(), hardware stopped OK
```

Comment: Are there any exceptions or other info reported in logcat?

Comment: What is data? Show your code leading up to this, and any exceptions please. Also, when you debug and step through, what is the value of data? Is it null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed (with the gracious help of Pixie )

the callback wasn't called because i had to use

```
Intent gotoImagePreview = new Intent(v.getContext(), CapturedImagePreview.class);
startActivityForResult(gotoImagePreview, 0);
```

at the end of my `PictureCallback jpegCallback = new PictureCallback()` callback so it'll store the image on the file system first because otherwise it calls `startActivityForResult` before it makes it to the last callback.